# rewrite condition to target Via: Varnish 1.1

Tags: .htaccess, varnish, rewrite

I have a Drupal site that uses Varnish.
I am trying to redirect people that come to a url starting with `/node` when they view the site via Varnish.

I have tried the following in the .htaccess file but it gives 500 errors.

> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Via} =1.1 varnish
>   RewriteRule ^node / [R=301,NC,L]

I haven't been able to find anything using google in relation to how to target the 'Via' section of a header.

Cheers,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Varnish installed here to test with, but it seems to me you're not escaping the plain text in your RewriteCond. The pattern is always considered to be a regex, so spaces and periods have special meaning. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Via} =1\.1\ varnish
RewriteRule ^node / [R=301,NC,L]
```

As an aside, this is a bit of a messy way to do things. Normally you would check the X-Forwarded-By header to determine if you're behind a proxy. As these can be spoofed and/or added by upstream proxies, you should either:

1. In the varnish VCL, remove all X-Forwarded-By headers from the request and re-add your own OR
2. add in a custom header (say: X-Real-Forwarded-By) and check for it's existence in your .htaccess

Comment: Cheers for your answer and explanation, I am checking  X-Forwarded as well but I only put the HTTP:Via one in my question because it was giving me problems.

Comment: Finally tried this out but I can't get this to work..

Answer (score 1):

Because Varnish isn't intended to do that you have to use a little trick for that.

For sending out a HTTP redirect the best way is to prepare a specific error handler and to raise this error handler depending on your requirements.

Step 1) Prepare an error handler to send a redirect

```
sub vcl_error {
  ...
  # redirect
  if (obj.status == 750) {
    set obj.status = 301;
    set obj.http.Location = "http://www.error-location.com/";
    return (deliver);
  }
  ...
}
```

Step 2) Raise prepared error handler

```
sub vcl_recv {
  ...
  # raise error if someone requests /node
  if (req.url ~ "^/node") {
    error 750;
  }
  ...
}
```

Alternatively you can set-up the error handler to use a dynamic target

```
sub vcl_error {
  ...
  # redirect to dynamic target
  if (obj.status == 750) {
    set obj.status = 301;
    set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
    return (deliver);
  }
  ...
}

...

sub vcl_recv {
  ...
  # redirect, if someone requests /node
  if (req.url ~ "^/node") {
    error 750 "http://www.error-location.com/";
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't have access to varnish so I will stick to the .htaccess solution above.